# How can I output tabs in the console?

Tags: vb.net

When I used to code in python there was a `\t` function when printing to leave a gap x amount of spaces until it reaches the next tab line, this was very useful for displaying tables in the console as all the bars would line up even when the data was of varying length. I've looked but can't seem to find a corresponding function in vb, wondering if anyone knew of one?

Comment: Use `VbTab` to print tabs instead of `\t`.

Comment: You can try `vbTab`

Comment: Thank you, just tried it and it works a treat.

Comment: ControlChars Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @previousbetine and @Anu6is

Use `VbTab` and review [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars?view=netframework-4.8) docs page regarding other ControlChars such as VbCrLf.

Thanks to @dbasnett for finding this docs page as well.